# USB to ethernet converter?

Tags: ethernet, usb

I have a router[1] which i use to connect to inter, it has one Ethernet and one USB port. I have two laptops running windows 7 so they are not able to the USB as the driver is not available. Thus I am able to use only one laptop with Internet at a time. I was thinking if there is a way to convert the USB port into Ethernet or any other way to go about making the other connection usable.

[1] UT-300R2U

Comment: I believe a better term is "ADSL modem" or at least "ADSL router". A "router" by itself strongly suggests a unit with at least 4 Ethernet ports and probably WiFi.

Comment: A switch has multiple ports, a router generally has one port. SOHO routers that you buy are routers + a switch, that is why there are more than one port, the connection is just made internally.

Answer (score 4):

Try connecting an ethernet hub or switch to the router, then connecting your laptops into the switch.

Comment: well that is the right way, but I want the fun and educative way

Comment: unless the router has built in drivers for a third party usb to ethernet adapters (not sure why they would ever do this) then you are flat out of luck.

Comment: Can't I something like use a micro controller to convert ethernet signals to usb signals?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work like that; there are no standard usb to ethernet interfaces. A good way to think about it would be that without these interfaces (unless third party drivers are present) there is no way for the router to accept data as being from an ethernet-type source. A router manufacturer would not include these drivers because it would affect their bottom line (you won't buy the upgraded model) and to a lesser degree because it is a very roundabout and inefficient solution to the problem (why not just use an ethernet switch?)

Comment: Well, while there is a standard USB class for Ethernet controllers, I agree that it is unlikely the router includes drivers for it.

Comment: I hate to take away the fun but I think it is highly unlikely that the router has a USB host at all.

Answer (score 1):

While what you are asking to do is not reasonably possible, a solution for your problem may be to connect one laptop to the router with an ethernet wire and set up an AdHoc wifi network to share the connection to the second laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect the modem to one computer via USB, then connect the two computers together via Ethernet. Have the first computer 'share' the connection with the second. I believe in windows it's called "Internet Connection Sharing" (ICS)

Comment: wud connecting both with just an ethernet wire do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Such as [these](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=usb+ethernet+adapter&cp=0&qe=dXNiIGV0aGVybmV0IA&qesig=Qn4a9ZYcDAQB4lFwxjIfjw&pkc=AFgZ2tkg23xlXUOTzWIDvARLMVRyaoPcb-OE3oFnew6aouGRVGZQ2CUhp074ERLMLXbVEBFoq_hPm5mImzT4fzJPiZhIct7G7Q&pf=p&sclient=psy&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=usb+ethernet+&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=ee6ab499cd4cc77a&ion=1), perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you would need to connect the modem to a USB host (an AVR, ARM or a bigger uC) and then write the drivers for your ADSL modem (this pretty much rules out anything not Linux based). If you do this then you can add (at least 2) Ethernet ports (probably with a switch chip) and then just route stuff around.

I do not believe there is an easier way to do what you want (apart from just buying a normal router).